# Using Shoulda matchers for attr_reader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

I would like to test a validation done on an attribute of the following class:

```
class R
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_reader :attribute

  validates :attributes, presence: true

  def initialize(attribute = {})
    @attribute = attribute
  end
end
```

Now my test is like this:

```
RSpec.describe R, type: :model do
  context 'validations' do
    subject { R.new(1) }

    it { should validate_presence_of(:attribute) }
  end
end
```

But this results in an error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `attributes=' for
```

If I change the attr_reader to an attr_accessor, then the test passes.

How can I leave the attr_reader as it is, and still get the test with the Shoulda matcher to pass?

Answer (score 2):

Shoulda's `validate_presence_of` works by trying to set an blank value on the argument, so it needs a setter method and can't work with attr_reader only.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably stub `attribute=` on the subject:

```
RSpec.describe R, type: :model do
  context 'validations' do
    subject { R.new(1) }
    before { subject.stub('attribute=') { |arg| subject.instance_variable_set(:attribute, arg) } }

    it { should validate_presence_of(:attribute) }
  end
end
```

Haven't tested this though.